# img src not working in Django using Bootstrap Carousel

Tags: python, html, django, bootstrap-4

Im trying to add an image to my bootstrap carousel but image is not loading.

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block html %}
{% load static %}

<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
 <head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
 </head>
 <body>
<div id="carouselExampleSlidesOnly" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
 <div class="carousel-inner">
   <div class="carousel-item active">
    <img class="d-block w-100" src="/Users/myname/Documents/django/ldn/static/images/phone.jpg" alt="First slide">
 </div>
 <div class="carousel-item">
  <img class="d-block w-100" src="{% static 'static/images/network.jpg' %}" alt="Second slide">
</div>
<div class="carousel-item">
  <img class="d-block w-100" src="../static/images/phone.jpg" alt="Third slide">
 </div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
{% endblock %}
```

Ive tried various methods as shown above but none work. My static/images folder is in my project root. Thanks

Comment: no doesn't solve it

Comment: What's the error on console?

Comment: "GET /static/images/phone.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 1672

Comment: Try this `{% static 'images/network.jpg' %}` . No need to mention static folder name. And add your static url path in `settings.py` to question.

Comment: thanks all working now. I moved the folder static folder to my accounts app which did the trick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
{% load static %}
    <html lang="en">
      <body>
          <img src="{% static 'img/logo.png' %}" >
      </body>
    </html>
```